# Paypal IPN handling in light of 2016-2017 security upgrade

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have questions about the [2016-2017 Merchant Security Roadmap](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US). I've been running a site that uses paypal for years and want to be in compliance with the [IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1916&viewlocale=en_US) requirement. I'm concerned that any answer that I receive here will not be an official one from a paypal representative, but it appears that I have no choice because the [PayPal support page](https://developer.paypal.com/support/)'s 'Ask our Community' link points here.

From what I can understand of the IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS requirement, it *only* refers to my site's post *back* to the paypal site to verify any incoming IPN. However, the document is confusing as it refers to some urls that I never use in my code, namely **ipnpb.paypal.com** and **ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com**.

I hope that someone might answer these questions for me:

1) My code posts back to either **https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr** for sandbox or **https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr** for production operations. Are these paypal endpoints going to keep working or must I change them?

2) If you send a 301 or 302 redirect to an incoming IPN request, will the paypal gateway follow the redirect and re-post the IPN to the new url? Of will PayPal just fail in the IPN attempt?

3) What if I modify my IPN handling url to send a 400 BAD REQUEST if any insecure (i.e., non-HTTPS) request is made to access it? Will the PayPal system take any action or will the notification just be lost because I declined to respond to it?

4) Given that paypal appears to store IPN urls for each transaction/recurring payment/subscription, what will the PayPal system do with my old transactions if they specify a non-HTTPS link for IPN notifications? Will paypal just switch it to HTTPS? Will the subscription/transaction/whatever be cancelled?  This seems like very important info if we want to comply.

EDIT: I would add to these questions two more:

5) does paypal offer a log of incoming API requests attempted on my account so that I can check if any use GET instead of POST?

6) does paypal have any UI or interface where I can get a list of the operations which might generate IPNs for my system such that I can inspect the IPN urls? My site has used 3-5 different urls on our site for IPN reporting and we still get IPNs coming in at some of them. It'd be nice to see if we might retire some of the old IPN scripts and also check of HTTPS or HTTP is used.

Comment: The whole Paypal test system is preposterous. It's artificially complicated to use, they have multiple domains to handle support, tests, development, there are crossed links between them that go round in circles. You rely on callbacks that are extremly difficult to debug, when they work at all. There is missing documentation in regards to crucial aspects like the ones you pose, their support staff is undertrained. I believe they are just letting Paypal die, since they own a part of Stripe too.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely unofficial, but since the directives were actually released a year ago (and modified to delay implementation to 2017), just sharing experience having implemented early - I missed the extension notice :)

- Bottom line: **TLS 1.2** for **ALL** secure communication with (bound for) Paypal

  > PayPal is upgrading the protocols used to secure all *external connections made **to** our systems*.

  If you get this done (and it could be tough if you're supporting a bunch of legacy resources), then you should be "good" as far as security roadmap is concerned.

  The emphasis on **to** is mine because they don't mention Paypal communications to *your* resources (the other way around: `Paypal -> your site`). IMHO, however, as an ecommerce application, and having gone through the effort of implementing things, I struggle to find a rationale for not implementing it across your application for any/all ecommerce/payment related flows (`redirecturl`, `cancelurl`, etc.)

You can verify/test your setup as [described here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US) - including your questions about redirects, error codes. Though IINM, Paypal documentation includes protocols for how to *properly* respond to IPN messages (or any of their APIs for that matter), as well as failure protocols (e.g. [retry mechanism](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/?mark=retry))

Your last question (subscriptions) will be best answered by Paypal. My opinion on the matter goes back to the "bottom line" - implement https/TLS 1.2 across the board..

Hth..

---

**Update**

> fails completely to address 301/302 redirects. It does seem to address what might happen if I send a 400 response. Sounds like that would result in PayPal retrying an IPN up to 15 times

- All APIs have *protocols* for use. The [official protocol for IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/) states:

  ```
  After receiving the IPN message from PayPal, your listener returns an empty
  HTTP 200 response to PayPal. Otherwise, PayPal resends the IPN message.
  ```

  If you want to *test* "Otherwise" (re: what if 30x/40x or *any http response other than an empty `200`*), then you *can* - but the protocol is as documented.

  Note: the `https://ipnpb.x.x` endpoint is documented here as well
- As far as endpoint URLs - the security upgrade is about HTTP 1.1 and TLS. The [documents include the **base** urls](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US) you mention (with dates on when they are ready for testing, and when production restrictions will be enforced) - re: so in the context of HTTP 1.1/TLS 1.2 whatever API endpoint resources (full paths - `[baseurl]/some/resource/endpoint`) are covered in the *security update*.

  I don't work for Paypal and don't claim mastery of all of their APIs. I'd look into the specific API you are using and check for API level changes - re: endpoints/resources/fields, etc., if any (the `ipnpb` resource is an example of some API level change/update).

Comment: I appreciate the information you have provided here, but you haven't addressed specifically any of the 4 questions I've asked. I have in fact gotten TLS 1.2 working, having already read that first link you sent. The second paypal link you sent is pretty informative, but fails completely to address 301/302 redirects. It does seem to address what might happen if I send a 400 response. Sounds like that would result in PayPal retrying an IPN up to 15 times.